# Links in Markdown with django-markdown-deux?

Tags: django, markdown, django-markdown-deux

I'm working with [django-markdown-deux](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux) and trying to include a Django URL in my markdown.

If I just include this raw in my template:

```
{% load markdown_deux_tags %}
{% url 'privacy_view' %}
```

It outputs `/privacy` just fine.

But as soon as I try to do a Markdown link:

```
[Privacy]({% url 'privacy_view' %}).
```

The text appears, but the link is just set to `#`.

What am I doing wrong?

Doing this doesn't help either:

```
[Privacy][1]
[1]: {% url 'privacy_view' %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hitting [python-markdown2 Issue #254](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/issues/254), where having `safe_mode: "escape"` results in broken relative links.

The markdown2 wrapper `django-markdown-deux` configures safe_mode [by default here](https://github.com/trentm/django-markdown-deux/blob/master/lib/markdown_deux/conf/settings.py). You can work around this by overriding `MARKDOWN_DEUX_DEFAULT_STYLE` in your django-settings.

```
MARKDOWN_DEUX_STYLES = { 'default': {
    "extras": {
        "code-friendly": None,
    },
    "safe_mode": False, # << here's the change
}}
```